# Causative を and は, are they interchangable?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-を, causation

For example in this sentence

> 「―――いえ。 **誰にも遠野くんは傷つけさせません**。 それだけは信じてください」 ……というか、そんな事より旅費とかパスポートとかを心配してしまう自分の小市民ぶりが情けない。

or this one

> 「……兄さん。秋葉にとって、兄さんは本当に一番大切な人だった。 だって、どんなに焦がれていても、それが手に入らないなら目障りなだけでしょう？」
>
> 「―――だから、殺してあげますね兄さん。一番大切なモノだったから、**貴方は他の誰にも傷つけさせません**」

Should the を particle be used here?
I was taught that in the causative form it was the topic who made に do the action on an object を, at least if the verb is transitive in its original form.

Isn't here the verb 傷つける which is transitive?

Answer (score 1):

> A. 誰{だれ}にも遠{とお}野{の}くん**は**傷{きず}つけさせません。  
>   B. 貴方{あなた}**は**他{ほか}の誰{だれ}にも傷{きず}つけさせません。

The plain forms of these sentences are as below.

> A'. 誰{だれ}にも遠{とお}野{の}くん**を**傷{きず}つけさせません。　　
>   B'. 貴方{あなた}**を**他{ほか}の誰{だれ}にも傷{きず}つけさせません。

When you add the particle は to を, を is almost always omitted, only は is spoken or written. In old Japanese, *をば* was used in the case, you may seldom see it nowadays.

The particle は is not only used for the topic marker, but also used for emphasis.  
は being used for emphasis, you can give an implied hint that others may be different from what は mentions.  
For example, A suggests indirectly that someone except for 遠{とお}野{の}くん may be injured, while A' doesn't have any contrast or comparison between 遠{とお}野{の}くん and others.

Comment: A:I won't let anyone hurt Tohno-Kun.  B:I won't late anyone else hurt Tohno-Kun.  Am i correct? I could rewrite them like this: 遠野くんは私が誰にも傷つけさせません

Comment: @Splikie, what's the difference between A and B? I don't think you've understood the contrastive wa correctly. The contrast goes on 遠野くん. 遠野くん, but not others.

Comment: I understand them like this. A:I won't let anyone hurt Tohno-kun(only him, as for others I don't care/don't know). B:I won't let anyone else hurt you (Only you, as for other I don't care/don't know). It gives me a vibe like "only X and as for the others it does not matter". Am I correct?